# может смартфон использоваться как RFID метка?

Tags: геолокация, позиционирование

может смартфон использоваться как RFID метка ?или нужно дополнительно прикрепить метку как на других объектов которых нужно позицианировать?

Answer (score 1):

Извните, я прочитал ряд Ваших вопросов, и вижу, что Вы часто задаёте слишком краткие вопросы, на которые невозможно ответить.

Так же и здесь.

Для начала - есть очень короткая и понятная статья: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFID

А теперь - внимание, вопрос: что именно означает "использовать телефон как rfid метку"? Вы ххотите телефон прикрепить к объекту и  сканировать его при приближении к объекту? Антенной?

Единственная разумная расшифровка вопроса, которая мне приходдит в голову - это "можно ли с телефона постоянно получать геопозицию". Да, можно. Примеров для Андроида (Вы же андроид испольуете?) много, вот, к примеру, такой код для xamarin:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/location/

Вообще, по Вашим вопросам, я думаю, что Вас интересуют особенности геолокации. Тогда лучше написать подробнее про задачу, уверен, что советчики найдутся.

Comment: мне кажется задачи как таковой нет ещё. она прощупывает технолочии чтоб сделать что-то новое - вайфай-радар-нг

Comment: насчет rfid - мне кажется более интересен пассивный съем, без установки приложений на телефоне "пинговать nfc модуль  телефона"

Comment: Да я  прочитала статью не только в википедии а еще много другие статьи .Но  хотела уточнить для себя  и понять как работает Технология RFID.
чтобы отследить  объекты нужно им прикрепить RFID метку правильно ? И когда объект к которому прикреплен RFID метка  попадает в зону  где расположены  RFID  считыватели можно получить местоположение объекта . 
так мой вопрос было в том что может ли  телефон отслеживаться как RFID метка ?(то есть  если телефон попадёт в зону  где расположены RFID считыватели, считыватели будут сканировать устройство и могут получить геопозицию  телефона ?)

Comment: объекты которые отслеживаются им заранее прикреплен метка RFID .                    
но получается что в смартфонах есть встроенные метки RFID ?
а вопрос для того что  если в смартфонах есть встроенные метки RFID и смартфон  попадая в зону действия считывателей отслеживается   как можно сделать так чтобы  смартфон не отслеживался ??

Comment: @MariaWilson, спасибо за пояснения, теперь вопрос стал понятен, очень интересный вопрос. Мне попалась такая информация: 
https://blog.adeveloper.ru/all/rfid-i-nfc-v-chem-raznica/ Прошу прощения за несколько негативный тон моего первого ответа. Как не отслеживать телефон rfid - считывателями - прямо скажу, не знаю. Было бы интересно узнать. Можно ли выключить NFC модуль в телефоне полностью?